# Spring data MongoDb @async for CRUD operations

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a spring boot project with spring data Mongodb, I would like to create the project with an no-blocking achitecture.
I red the documentation of [Spring Data MongoDB](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-async) for @Async annotation, but it refers only to the custom queries.
I would like to use async method also for CRUD operations (insert, findAll, find, delete, deleteAll)

Do you know how I can do that?